# When creating Zoom I am getting invalid access token error when my keys are valid

Tags: python, django, django-views, zoom-sdk

```
import requests
import json

API_KEY = 'API KEY'
API_SEC = 'SECRET KEY'

zoom_api_url = 'https://api.zoom.us/v2/users/me/meetings'

meeting_details = {
    "topic": "The title of your Zoom meeting",
    "type": 2,
    "start_time": "2024-02-27T10:00:00",
    "duration": "45",
    "timezone": "Europe/Madrid",
    "agenda": "Test Meeting",
    "settings": {
        "host_video": "true",
        "participant_video": "true",
        "join_before_host": "False",
        "mute_upon_entry": "False",
        "watermark": "true",
        "audio": "voip",
        "auto_recording": "cloud"
    }
}

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

auth = (API_KEY, API_SEC)


response = requests.post(zoom_api_url, headers=headers, auth=auth, data=json.dumps(meeting_details))

print(response.json())
```

After I am getting access token, but its saying invalid access token.
I have added keys and allowed authentication on Zoom.
I have tested it with postman as well as through my django app

From every platform I am getting same error.

> **Invalid Access Token**

I tried to create access with jwt.io too but still its not working.

If anyone can help, what is wrong?

Comment: Which authentication method are you using **Server-To-Server OAuth** or **OAuth**?

Comment: Note the tag description on [tag:api] which says "Do not use".